# excel file fill all the values follow the first ID

Tags: excel

i tried wanted to fill up all the values based on the first ID given but failed.

as you can see from below image, i expected '91ablee' for all row under ablee ID.

[image]

formula used : ="insert into tb_brpriv values(default,'91"&A2&"','"&E2&"')"

Comment: [Why not images of Code and Sample Data](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/285557#285557) and [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this in H2,

```
="insert into tb_brpriv values(default,'91"&INDEX(A:A, MATCH("zzz",A$1:A2))&"','"&E2&"')"
```

The *zzz* with no *match_type* parameter tells the [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) to supply the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) with the row number containing the last available text value. The A$1:A2 will grow as it is filled down.